# extjs and Win8 and AppStore and Win JS?

Tags: extjs

Can I use extjs and WinJS together to create a Win8 app?

"apps written in JavaScript can certainly use jQuery, Modernizer, Dojo, prototype.js, Box2D, and others, with the caveat that some functionality, especially UI and script injection, might not be supported."

What is a UI caveat? :-)

just found "The app host is more or less Internet Explorer 10 without the browser chrome" ... that doesn't sound hopeful, right?

Comment: Why doesn't IE10 without chrome sound hopeful?

Answer (score 0):

The context warns you that some User Interface functionality might not be supported. You can use both of the library's for your app.

Edit to your edit: Windows is trying something different.. again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bigger question might be whether you'd get an app written in ExtJS through the win8 app approval process.

The design paradigms that MS are trying to promote, don't map very well onto Ext components out of the box.

You'd have to do quite a chunk of work to adhere to the design suggestions and I'd expect that there may be conflicts between some of the layout manager bits of Ext and the layout managers of WinJS (could be wrong though).